# Как приостановить выполнение обработчика событий WPF?

Tags: c#, события, wpf

Есть условие, находящееся в блоке обработчика события:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
```

Нужно, чтобы при некотором условии, например

```
                if (txt.Text == "")
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Вы заполнили не все предоставленные поля");
                    //Здесь нужно выполнить нечто, что остновило бы вып-е обр-ка события

                }
```

выполнение обработчика не продолжалось.

Как это можно реализовать, не подскажете?

IF - это вложенный цикл. Вложен в foreach.

Решение:

```
            byte doNotRepeat = 0;
            foreach (//Условие) 
            {
                if (doNotRepeat != 1 && txt.Text == "")
                {
                    doNotRepeat = 1;
                    MessageBox.Show("Вы заполнили не все предоставленные поля");
                    doNotRepeat = 0;
                    return;

                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ежели у вас оно в `foreach`, то нужно объявлять отдельную переменную. Почти так, как у вас, только можно использовать тип `bool`, а не `int`.

```
bool stop = false;
foreach (string item in Processes)
{
    if (stop)
        break;
}
```

Comment: О, простите, вы правы!